# How can I change the padding in jquery range

Tags: jquery, css, function, padding, onchange

How can I set the CSS padding using jQuery?

```
$('#Range2').change(function () {
    $('.lil').css({ padding: this.value + 'px' + '0px' + '0px' + '0px' });
});
```

Comment: create some class and apply that class to .lil

Comment: I agree with @Ganesh_Devlekar this is a much cleaner method

Comment: Sometimes you can't.  Like if your job is to just use javascript to change things.  It's happened to me before

Comment: Just to point out, in this specific case, `$('.lil').css('padding-top', this.value + 'px');` would do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#Range2').change(function() {
    $('.lil').css({ padding: this.value + 'px 0px 0px 0px' });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKY2A/352/)

or pure javascript

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKY2A/357/)

```
function changePadding() {
    lil.style["padding-top"] = this.value + 'px';
}


var lil = document.querySelector('.lil'),
    Range2 = document.querySelector('#Range2');

Range2.addEventListener("change",changePadding,false);
```

Comment: For consitency's sake, I would put "padding" in quotes.  Yes, javascript knows what padding is, but if you ever wanted to do `padding-left` you would need quotes (`'padding-left'`)

Comment: @ntgCleaner  then use  `$('.lil').css("padding-left", this.value + 'px');`  demo http://jsfiddle.net/GKY2A/354/

Comment: @ntgCleaner You know you can write `paddingLeft` without quote too? So yeah, it is just personnal preference if you put the quote or not, no *"consitency's sake"*

Comment: @David Kern padding shorthand is `padding:top right bottom left` so it will look like this  `$('.lil').css({ padding: this.value + 'px 0px '+ this.value+'px  0px' });` live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/GKY2A/358/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, you can do that, and to David's point, he's asking how to write `paddingTop`, `paddingRight`, `paddingBottom` and `paddingLeft`.   Sometimes this camel case isn't correct or is different than expected, so it's easier to use quotes

Comment: @ntgCleaner i'm not gonna argue on anything related to a personal preference (i.e using camel case or quotes), but unless you can bring a proof of what you're saying, camel does not do anything different than putting them inside a quote. I've tested it in i.e8 and it work fine. Your statement *"it's easier to use quotes"* is false, it's an opinion.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I wasn't intending to argue anything. Yes, it's an opinion because I would rather prefer to use actual CSS styles rather than a javascript equivalent. And I'm sorry but you saying "is false, it's an opinion" is false in it's own right. Opinions are neither true nor false. I was simply lending another way to do things, neither are right or wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.lil').css({ "padding": this.value + 'px 0px 0px 0px' });
```

This doesn't work?

Comment: By the way, it can be simply `0` instead of `0px`

Comment: @Regent Correct, though the OP wants "px" in there it seems

Answer (score 1):

Just add spaces

```
$('.lil').css({ padding: this.value + 'px ' + '0px ' + '0px ' + '0px' });
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but perhaps because whitespace in JS are ignored. - edit: Oh, nevermind, you meant spaces in the strings... my bad

Comment: The + concatenation is wrong. you will wind up with: 0px0px0px –

Comment: Whitespace under the quotes, as I have written above, are NOT ignored in any language.

Comment: @rm-vanda it will result in `0px 0px 0px`, not in `0px0px0px`.

Comment: @rm-vanda, false, + concatenation is alright, spaces are inside of strings!

Comment: you're right, I must be cross-eyes. I didn't see the spaces the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#Range2').change(function() {    
  $('.lil').css("padding", this.value + 'px 0px 0px 0px' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#Range2').change(function () {
    $('.lil').css('padding', this.value + 'px' + '0px' + '0px' + '0px');
});
```

Comment: The `+` concatenation is wrong. you will wind up with: 
`0px0px0px`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

by adding `' '` it will also take other variables

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/q62whjre/2/)

```
    function padding() {
        a = $('#Range').val() + 'px'
        b = $('#Range1').val() + 'px'
        c = $('#Range2').val() + 'px'
        d = $('#Range3').val() + 'px'

        $('.test').css({
            'padding': a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d
        })        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and can Apply where you want

Create CSS

```
 .lil{
 padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Apply It Using Jquery

```
$('#Range2').change(function() {
$(this).addClass( "lil" );
});
```